# Plug in analog sensor into digital pin

Tags: digital, analog

If I take an Arduino (samd21, if it matters) and plug in an analog sensor/pot into a digital pin and then set that pin to be an input, would digitalRead(#) trigger HIGH and LOW at some threshold point?  Or does it not work at all?

Comment: I don't have the parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to SAMD21 the digital input pin detects **HIGH** if the voltage on pin is higher than 0.55 of supply voltage. So at 3.3 V it is **1.8 V**.

The input pin detects **LOW** if the voltage is lower than 0.3 of supply voltage. It is **0.99 V** at 3.3 V.

For voltages between these values (1 V to 1.8 V) the result can be HIGH or LOW.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you read the datasheet you will find a set of voltage specifications. The ones you are interested in are VIH and VIL.

Most MCUs use a "Schmitt Trigger" for the inputs. This means that when the voltage rises above the HIGH threshold (VIH) the input switches to HIGH. When the voltage drops below the LOW threshold (VIL) the input switches to LOW.  This "hysteresis" provides a certain amount of noise rejection to give a clean digital input signal.